# Java WAR - Load Spring beans from an external JAR

Tags: spring-mvc, jar, dependency-injection, war, autowired

I would like to load inside my Spring MVC Web Application (packaged as WAR) some Spring framework beans annotated with **`@Service`** from an external jar, which is in charge of accessing a database and **located in the classpath** under /WEB-INF/lib. If possible, it would be desirable to load them automatically using the **`@Autowired`** annotation.

I have followed successfully the solution in this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374458/how-to-properly-load-and-configure-spring-beans-from-an-external-utility-jar/17379767#comment25422040_17379767):

```
this.ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("services-context.xml");
this.myAService = ctx.getBean("myAService");
```

However, this solution uses Spring API function **getBean** which is considered a bad practice (see [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad)).

I also tried, without luck two more things to load the external jar´s applicationContext:

- WAR´s appContext.xml:

  ```
  <import resource="classpath*:/WEB-INF/lib/pathToExternalJar/applicationContext.xml">
  ```
- WAR´s web xml -> load the jar´s appContext as described here ([link3](http://www.gridshore.nl/2008/05/13/spring-application-context-loading-tricks/)). (e.g. *applicationContext.xml):

  ```xml
      <context-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>
              classpath:localSpringContext.xml
              classpath:*applicationContext.xml
          </param-value>
      </context-param>
  ```

What is the best approach to load those beans properly and  how should it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAR´s appContext.xml and WAR´s web xml are both feasible. If you need to run integration tests based on both localSpringContext.xml and external jar's applicationContext.xml frequently, I recommend the WAR´s appContext.xml approach.

Updated1:

WAR´s appContext.xml:

```
<import resource="classpath:{classpath}/applicationContext.xml"/>
```

WAR´s web xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:localSpringContext.xml
        classpath:{classpath}/applicationContext.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For example, if your applicationContext.xml is under package :com/gmail/hippoom

you can get it by classpath:com/gmail/hippoom/applicationContext.xml or classpath*:applicationContext.xml with wildcard.

Comment: As I commented in the post I had no succeed using those approaches. How should the string entered as resource (in WAR´s appContext.xml approach) look like (please, provide an example)? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the needed path was really my problem. I finally did it thanks to your help :) with: **<import resource="classpath:myExternalApplicationContext.xml"/>** as the XML was directly under the JAR (currently, not inside any package as com/gmail/hippoom). So -> {classpath} = "". Now with that import I load perfectly the external applicationContext. Thanks again for your help.